# Finding best fit parameters for a set of equations with known uncertainties

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, least-squares, uncertainty

As a follow up to another question: 
[solve linear equations given variables and uncertainties: scipy-optimize?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23231520/solve-linear-equations-given-variables-and-uncertainties-scipy-optimize)[solve linear equations given variables and uncertainties: scipy-optimize?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23231520/solve-linear-equations-given-variables-and-uncertainties-scipy-optimize)

It appears to me that I have a very similar problem. I am relatively new to py and used it mostly to sort and reduce data with pandas.

I have a set of linear equations, where I want to find the best fit parameters. However, the dataset has known uncertainties that need to be considered given in parentheses.

```
x1*99(1)+x2*45(1)=52(0.2)
x1*1(0.5)+x2*16(1)=15(0.1)
```

Moreover, there are the following constraints:

```
x1>=0
x2>=0
x1+x2=1
```

My approach would be to treat the equations as constraints and solve the sum of the residues as it has been shown in the (simplified) example above.

Solving this without uncertainties is not the issue. I ask to get a hint on how to account for the uncertainties while finding the best fit parameters.

Comment: The word "uncertainties" is somewhat vague here: does this mean that the first right hand side has a gaussian distribution with mean 52 and standard deviation 0.2 ?

Comment: It's very complicated problem. Imagine you have some trial values of `x1` and `x2`. How do you define chi^2 or similar goodness-of-fit statistic? At this point you have somehow inverted set of equations where you know `x1` & `x2` and your goal is to find exact values of coefficients with priors: 99+1, 45+-1, 52+-0.2 etc. You solve for these and then calculate goodness-of-fit statistic. Clearly, optimising for `x1` and `x2` is a non-linear problem and requires MCMC or similar.

Answer (score 1):

A quick and dirty approach would be to generate synthetic datasets for the coefficients (a number with an uncertainty corresponds to a normal distribution with a given mean and variance). For each realization you simply solve the 2-by-2 system and collect the distribution of x1 and x2.